# How to add specific script to WordPress webpage that will working with user input and databases

Tags: plugins, functions, database, javascript, scripts

We are new to WordPress and want to create Website that will be taking user input, running specific script through databases using that input and then outputting specific results on the web-page or sending them to email.

I have found a way to connect WordPress page with databases, but not sure how to include script in between that will be making all calculations. Would appreciate any help and advice.

P.S. we have a Python script but I guess we should convert it to php?

Thanks
Farid

Comment: You could just use WordPress as a front-end that queues up jobs which are run by a separate process, and you could still use the Python script for the separate process. How much work is the script / how long does it take to run?

Comment: script takes no more than 5 mins to finish. I understood queue part, but how to pick an input data and then perform background calculations on it with that script and existing databases? Just not sure how to connect all these within WordPress. would appreciate any help.